# No sound after upgrading to VLC 2.0.1

Tags: 11.10, sound, vlc

Every sound is working on my 11.10 64bit machine except of VLC. I upgraded via the n-muench PPA from 1.1 to 2.0 and since that moment there is no sound anymore.

The only sound bits I get are strange distorted sounds. Any ideas what is wrong?

ALSA recognises VLC and its demand for sound. The console does not say a word about sound.

Comment: Does this still happen if you upgrade it with the official VLC PPA?

Comment: Yes, I tried the muench-PPA and the official (ppa:videolan/stable-daily) - hm. I have no idea...

Comment: I didn't upgrade `VLC`, but when I open mpeg-files I recorded with `Me TV` I also hear distorted and echo sounds ... When I pause/play or jump in the timeline(?) several times it mostly works then. Using VLC in the same user session afterwards (even after closing and reopen it) works without problems. I hope you understand what I mean. I could explain this better in German ;)

Comment: Do it, I am German as well ;) But I know what you mean. And that's not the problem, because VLC 1.1.12 works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had sound working on my 11.10 64bit machine except in VLC.

After reboot, I restored audio in vlc 2.01 by muting a video and then unmuting. Strange.